# Can i find the length of a dictionary in JAC?

Tags: jaseci

I can find the length of a list in JAC using list.length but not the dictionary. Is there a function to do this ?

```
walker init {

    a = ["1","2"];
    std.out(a.length);
    x = {
        "x" :4,
        "y" : 5,
        "x" :6
    };

    std.out(x.length);
}
```

I wanted the length of this dictionary but it throws an error saying it's not a list. What is the dictionary variation to find the length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know one way to achieve this is get the keys of the dictionary (which is a list) and then get its length. SO something like this

```
walker init {

    a = ["1","2"];
    std.out(a.length);
    x = {
        "x" :4,
        "y" : 5,
        "x" :6
    };

    std.out(x.dict::keys.length);
}
```

Comment: Also a quick one, a good 'jaconic' way to do it would be `std.out(x.d::keys.l::length);`